# void* conversion to int*** in mouse callback function (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to save the coordinates of the 4 points that I click on the image in 4x2 matrix. To do this I'm using the following code.

```
static void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    int*** p=(int***)param;


    p*=new int*[4];
    (*p)[0]=new int[2];
    (*p)[1]=new int[2];
    (*p)[2]=new int[2];
    (*p)[3]=new int[2];

    int i=0;
    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && i<4){
        (*p)[i][0]=x;
        (*p)[i][1]=y;
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ....

    int** p;
    namedWindow("rgb image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow( "rgb image", bgrImage );
    setMouseCallback("rgb image", mouseEvent, &p);

    ...
}
```

The problem I saw during debugging is that the line "int*** p=(int***)param;" is not working. I checked several sources and think it may be a 64-bit issue. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Include compiler/runtime error...

Comment: If `param` *does* point to an `int**`, the conversion is fine. However it is hard to say without seeing more, and more importantly without fixing the syntax...

Comment: debugger says p is not accessable. The problem is the value of param is not assigned to p.

Comment: So initialize `p` to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

my crystal ball tells me, that you're trying to get the 4 points nessecary for a perspective transform ;).

```
static void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    vector<Point2f> *p = (vector<Point2f>*)param;

    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && p->size()<4){
        p->push_back(Point2f(x,y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ....

    vector<Point2f> p;
    namedWindow("rgb image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow( "rgb image", bgrImage );
    setMouseCallback("rgb image", mouseEvent, (void*)(&p));

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
int nth_count=0;
static void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    int*** address_of_p=(int***)param;

    (*p)[nth_count]=new int[2];

    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && nth_count<4){
        (*p)[nth_count][0]=x;
        (*p)[nth_count][1]=y;
        nth_count++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int** p;
    p = new int*[4];
    namedWindow("rgb image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow( "rgb image", bgrImage );
    setMouseCallback("rgb image", mouseEvent, &p);
}
```